# Implicit function theorem, differentiable path

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

I need to show that the equations: $$x^2y+xy^2+t^2=1$$ $$x^2+y^2 -2yt=0$$ is difinding a differentiable path $\vec{\gamma}=({x}_{(t)},{y}_{(t)})$ at the point $(x,y)=(-1,1)$.

after that I should find the tangent line for this path in this specific point.

So my idea is to use the implicit function theorem here but this is the first time I see expression with the  more variables in the equation than the point I am asked to show. what I usually do is check if the point I have given is satisfy $F(x,y)=0$ but here I have the extra variable $t$. what I should do?  I feel that I should use the implicit theorem here but not sure how to do it in this conditions.

Comment: First of all write down the statement of the implicit function theorem. Because the theorem is true in a very general circumstance (not necessarily restricted to functions of $2$ variables)

Comment: That's what I did, what is the $F$ I need to define? to apply the implicit function theorem I need to make sure $F(,x,y)=0$ in $(-1,1)$ but I cant do that as long I have the variable $t$ in the equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $F: \Bbb{R}^3 \to \Bbb{R}^2$ by $F(t,x,y) = (x^2y + xy^2 + t^2, x^2 + y^2-2yt)$. We're going to apply the implicit function theorem to this function $F$. Now, notice that $F(1,-1,1) = (1,0)$. Also, the Jacobian matrix  of partial derivatives is
\begin{align}
F'(t,x,y) &=
\begin{pmatrix}
2t & 2xy + y^2 & x^2 + 2xy \\
-2y & 2x & 2y - 2t
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
So,
\begin{align}
F'(1,-1,1) &=
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & -1 \\
-2 & -2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Note that every $2 \times 2$ submatrix is invertible. So, by the implicit function theorem, you can solve for any two out of the three variables as a $C^{\infty}$ function of the third. In particular, you can solve for $x$ and $y$ as a function of $t$, in a neighbourhood of $t=1$, which is what you had to prove.

---

You're probably more comfortable with the lower-dimensional situation where $f: \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}$, and if there is a point $(a,b)$ where $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a,b) \neq 0$, then in a neighbourhood of $(a,b)$, you can express $y$ as a smooth function of $x$. Well, this question is just a generalization to more variables.

Since you want to solve for $x,y$ as a function of $t$, you simply have to check if
\begin{align}
\det \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial y}\end{pmatrix} \neq 0
\end{align} 
(all the derivatives being evaluated at the appropriate point). And as I've shown above, this is indeed the case. For the statement of the theorem in the general case, take a look at [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem).

Comment: Thank you for the deep explanation, I still didn't understand why you chose the point $t=1$? From what I understand we need that the function $F(t,x,y) = (x^2y + xy^2 + t^2, x^2 + y^2-2yt)$ will get the value $(0,0)$ so we will be able to use the implicit theorem

Comment: @Sagigever No, we need to find $(t_0,x_0,y_0)$ such that $F(t_0,x_0,y_0) = (1,0)$, which is the RHS of your given equations. If instead I defined a different function $G(t,x,y) = (x^2y + xy^2 + t^2 -1, x^2 + y^2 -2yt)$, then I would have to find $(t_0,x_0,y_0)$ such that $G(t_0,x_0,y_0) = (0,0)$. Basically, you have to find the point in the domain such that it equals the RHS of your equations. Then, you can apply the IFT. In this case, your question told you to pick $(x_0,y_0) = (-1,1)$. So, I simply verified that $t_0=1$ works.